# How is border-bottom horizontally centered on CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: Example GIF]

Hi,
I use the Bootstrap library but when it comes to the border-bottom, I don't know how to get it to the center.

Could you help?

```css
.full-nav .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/materials/arg0.svg" /></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `border-bottom` just turns on the border of the bottom of an element. There is no 'centering' involved, the border stretches the full width of the element.

Comment: from the duplicate simply make the position `center` and you get it

Comment: You want the css property text-decoration: line-through